# Group lists in the new Outlook

Tags: outlook.com, contacts-group

None of the groups I had previously created in Hotmail are showing up in the new Hotmail Outlook. I have read your suggestions for other people, but when I open People there is no tab on the top that says Groups. Only 'Save as Group'. So I have tried to re-create groups but when I can start a new group, with the same name as an old group it tells me I have a group with that name already. I just can't find it to add contacts to it.

This email is used for a non-profit soccer club, which means I have 20 different groups with 100s of contact. I would hate to loose this information or the ability to add new members to existing groups.

Comment: Could you please link to the other suggestions so that we know which ones you're referring to?

Answer (score 1):

Please follow these steps to be able see your groups and to add/remove/modify group properties:

1- If you are in Outlook, then click on the down arrow beside the Outlook logo on the top left. Alternatively, go to the [People page here and sign in if you aren't already signed in](http://people.live.com).

[image]

2- You should see something along these lines:

[image]

Now, your groups and individual contacts are in the same list. Type in the name of the group to filter it.

3- You can tell it is a group because of the logo beside it.

[image]

4- Click on the name of the group and then click "Edit". Now, you can modify who is in the group.

[image]

Hope this helps :)